# Custom threebox layer for react-map-gl

Tags: three.js, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl, threebox

I am trying to add a custom 3D object to my `react-map-gl` instance. Unfortunately, I can't find any examples that have successfully implemented this besides [`mapbox-gl-threelayer`](https://github.com/salgum1114/mapbox-gl-threelayer). This package is a bit outdated for my needs- it relies on an v1 instance of `mapbox-gl` that doesn't support 3d terrain as the current v2 package does.

Does anyone have a suggestion or recommendation on how to add 3d objects to a `react-map-gl` custom layer with 3d terrain enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "threebox" and it works well!

https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox

Either for mapbox or maplibre, this threebox module shows gltf, glb, fbx etc. files for me